# Is there a name for music that is just harmony + melody?

Tags: terminology

For example, GreenSleeves

[image]

Is there a name for this type of composition: chord/harmony + melody? I'm not looking for the genre, which is traditional folk music.

Comment: I have also heard this format referred to as "piano lead sheet" or "piano fake".   I believe this was because the piano arrangement was built off of a lead sheet/fake book version of the melody, expanding the chord letters into piano clef.

Comment: I don't understand this question. The vast majority of music is composed of harmony and melody. Can you add an example of a piece that is **not** "just harmony + melody"?

Comment: @ToddWilcox we have chorale and fugue which doesn't follow the pattern from above example. Greensleeves could be written in fugue and chorale.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're asking about what we call **texture**.

Your example is **homophonic** (noun: homophony), meaning that one part dominates while the other parts merely provide harmonic support. Some would use the term **melody-dominated homophony** for something like Greensleeves.

Something like a Bach fugue is **polyphonic**, meaning there are many independent musical lines.

There is also **monophonic** music, which is just a single melodic line either played by one instrument or by multiple instruments in parallel motion.

Comment: Would it change if the chords were broken chords?

Comment: Nope! Even a piano sonata with the melody in the right hand and an Alberti bass in the left hand would still be considered homophonic.

Comment: Are you sure that monophonic has to be unison or octaves? Pretty sure any parallel lines are monophonic, like fifths.

Comment: Good call; or the parallel perfect fourths of ca. 10th--13th century!

Comment: hey that is the exact name I'm looking for: melody-dominated homophony

Answer (score 4):

You may be looking for the word 'homophonic'.   This describes a musical texture that in clearly divided into a melody and an accompaniment.   The opposite is 'polyphonic' which describes music where multiple melodic strands intertwine.

Beyond the most basic singing to a strummed guitar, absolutely pure homophony is rare.  In a SATB hymn tune, we try to give each voice a melodic line rather than just jumping around randomly to 'fill in the chord'.   Even in the simple 'Greensleeves' version you posted, the chords follow a downwards scale rather than jumping all over the place.  This gives a little contrapuntal interest to the music.

Comment: I remember talking about that descending baseline as counterpoint.